# Is it possible to change the default scan folder on an Eye-Fi Wireless SD Card?

Tags: fat32

By default [Eye-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye-Fi) cards scan the DCIM folder (and subfolders) used by most digital cameras for new images to upload.

Is there a way of changing this to a different folder?

In my particular case I'm using a Kodak photo scanner (P461) that uses a PHOTO(N) folder format to store the scanned images, as far as I know the device has no configuration interface to alter this setting so that doesn't seem to be an option.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20140312010947/http://forums.eye.fi/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=2626) topic on the Eye-Fi forums is the closest I've come to a solution, but a perfunctory investigation of Disk Probe doesn't make it obvious what needs to be modified on the card. It seems to rely on knowledge of editing fat32 directory entries.

Comment: The method suggested by that topic is to edit the card's firmware. I never had an Eye-Fi card, but it would amaze me if the firmware was externally accessible.

Comment: Yes, my investigations to date suggest you can't edit the firmware. But the implication of that topic seems to be that you can somehow use Disk Probe to edit the FAT32 entries to re-direct PHOTO(N) to DCIM (or some variation of that strategy) and that's the information I'm after.

Comment: It can also mean updating the fat32 tables to rename the folder. But that's a funny way of doing that, since any computer can rename a folder. Of course one will afterward need to rename it back for the camera to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use Disk Probe (on XP only, I've yet to get it to write the changes on Win7) to modify the cluster a FAT Directory references. This method can be used to redirect the DCIM folder (or a subfolder) to point to the folder used by a different scan device.

**Whether this is a good idea or not is a different matter and you use this at your own risk.**

1. Insert the Eye-Fi card either in it's USB Card Reader or directly
   into an SSD slot and note the drive letter it's installed as
   (assumed to be F:\ for simplicity)
2. Ensure all Windows Explorer windows for the card and sub-directories are closed.
3. Run Disk Probe
4. Select Drives->Logical Volume
5. In the `Open Logical Volume` dialog double-click F:\ in the Logical Volumes list
6. Click the `Set Active` button for the Handle F: has been selected as. You can leave the handle as read-only for now.
7. Select Tools->Search Sectors...
8. Check `Exhaustive Search`, enter DCIM in `Enter characters to search for` and Search
9. You should find a match (mine is at 8192). Select No on the "Found match..." dialog to cancel the rest of the search.
10. Select Sectors->Read and increase `Number of Sectors` to at least two so that the whole directory table is included.
11. Find DCIM in the ASCII on the right of the Disk Probe screen, this is the start of the FAT entry for the directory. Make a note of the hex value of the 27th byte of the record (each entry is 32bytes), this is the directory cluster reference.
    **This value is needed to revert the DCIM directory back to normal use if required.**
12. Find the entry for the directory you want to redirect DCIM to and again make a note of the 27th byte in the record.
13. Go back to the 27th byte of the DCIM record and change it to the value noted in step 12.
14. Select Sectors->Write and then click `Write it` on the Write Sector dialog. A warning will come up if you opened the sectors as read-only. Yes to overwrite if you're happy to make the change.

Opening the DCIM directory in Windows Explorer will now show the contents of the target directory.